# Creating or mimicing eth0

Tags: wireless, networking, matlab

I am using an ultrabook (Thinkpad X1 Carbon) that has no eth0 device - it only has wlan. Installation is Xubuntu on 12.04

However, MATLAB requires an eth device during installation. Is it possible to set up some sort of fake eth device, that goes through the wlan device, in order to install MATLAB?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  I think you can accomplish that, by creating a virtual ethernet (eth0).  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  (where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP address)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually googled some more in the meantime and found a solution on the matlab forums. The answer there was to create a dummy interface using modprobe. Thanks a lot for your help anyways!